# ¿ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAll')?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a crud application from a tutorial but I am running into problems. I got it to work but made a change and it stopped working.
I show code and error obtained. Note that I got it to work but made a change and it stopped working, the problem must not be far away.

```
app.module.ts without errors

app-routing.module.ts without errors
```

the pokemon component is connected to the Pokedex service facilitating the connection to the firestore database.
I could not inject the service into the builder because it was not templating.

```
pokemon.component.ts:

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { Observable, Subject, filter, tap, takeUntil } from "rxjs";
import { PokedexFirestoreService } from "src/app/services/pokedex-firestore.service";
import { FormComponent } from "./form/form.component";
import { Pokemon } from "./pokemon.interface";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon',
  templateUrl: './pokemon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon.component.scss']
})
export class PokemonComponent implements OnInit {
  

  selectedPokemon?: Pokemon;
  destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
  pokedexService!: PokedexFirestoreService;
  allPokemon$!: Observable<Pokemon[]>;

  constructor(
    private readonly dialog: MatDialog,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allPokemon$ = this.pokedexService.getAll();
  }

  addPokemon() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FormComponent, {
      data: {
        pokemon:{}
      },
      width: '40%',
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        tap((pokemon) => this.pokedexService.create(pokemon)),
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  updatePokemon() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FormComponent, {
      data: { ...this.selectedPokemon },
      width: '40%',
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        tap((pokemon) => this.pokedexService.update(pokemon)),
        tap((pokemon) => this.selectPokemon(pokemon)),
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  selectPokemon(pokemon: Pokemon) {
    this.selectedPokemon = pokemon;
  }

  deletePokemon() {
    this.pokedexService.delete(this.selectedPokemon!.id);
    this.selectedPokemon = undefined;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
  }
}


pokedex-firestore.service.ts

import {
  CollectionReference,
  DocumentData,
  addDoc,
  collection,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
} from '@firebase/firestore';
import { collectionData, docData, Firestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Pokemon } from '../components/mis-app/pokemon/pokemon.interface';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})`enter code here`
export class PokedexFirestoreService {
  
  private pokemonCollection: CollectionReference<DocumentData>;

  constructor(private readonly firestore: Firestore, private store: AngularFirestore) {
    this.pokemonCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'pokemon');
  }

  // getAll() {
  //   return collectionData(this.pokemonCollection, {
  //     idField: 'id',
  //   }) as Observable<Pokemon[]>;
  // }

  getAll() {
    return this.store.collection('pokemon').valueChanges({idField:'id'}) as Observable<Pokemon[]>;
  }

  get(id: string) {
    const pokemonDocumentReference = doc(this.firestore, `pokemon/${id}`);
    return docData(pokemonDocumentReference, { idField: 'id' });
  }

  create(pokemon: Pokemon) {
    return addDoc(this.pokemonCollection, pokemon);
  }

  update(pokemon: Pokemon) {
    const pokemonDocumentReference = doc(
      this.firestore,
      `pokemon/${pokemon.id}`
    );
    return updateDoc(pokemonDocumentReference, { ...pokemon });
  }

  delete(id: string) {
    const pokemonDocumentReference = doc(this.firestore, `pokemon/${id}`);
    return deleteDoc(pokemonDocumentReference);
  }
}`enter code here`

the error generated:

core.mjs:6494 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAll')
at PokemonComponent.ngOnInit (pokemon.component.ts:27:44)
at callHook (core.mjs:2551:1)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2520:1)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2471:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9510:1)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10692:1)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9291:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9545:1)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10646:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9519:1)

please, I am new to this and need help, thank you very much.
```

Answer (score 0):

your pokedexService is undefined

You should inject service into component

```
constructor(
    private readonly dialog: MatDialog,
    private pokedexService: PokedexFirestoreService;
) {}
```